# How to override Postgres' array_agg(expression) function?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm using hibernate to call the Postgres `array_agg` function. The problem is that I need to call the function with an order by included. I cannot pass the order by through hibernate in the correct syntax so I need to create a function that does exactly what `array_agg` does with ordering being automatic. Here's what I need to duplicate in a function:

```
array_agg(table.TEXT order by table.text asc)
```

I've tried and tried but I cannot figure it out - and google isn't helping much. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not part of the function, it's part of the SQL syntax. Fix your framework. It's open source, so submit a patch.

Comment: I know that it is not part of the function. That's why I said that I need to create a custom function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out just by creating a custom aggregate function and using the final function (FFUNC)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION order_func(anyarray) RETURNS anyarray AS $BODY$ 
     BEGIN
        return ARRAY(SELECT unnest($1) ORDER BY 1);
     END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_order_func(anyelement) (
SFUNC=array_append,
STYPE=anyarray,
FFUNC=order_func,
INITCOND='{}'
);
```

This will then pass the aggregated array to the sorting function.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute the missing feature by feeding an ordered set to the aggregate function - which works in Postgres but is not the standard SQL way to do this (as @Richard mentioned in his comment):

```
SELECT array_agg(sub.text) AS ordered_array
FROM  (SELECT text FROM tbl ORDER BY text) sub
```

Or, for a simple case like this, just use the [array constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) instead:

```
SELECT ARRAY( SELECT text FROM tbl ORDER BY 1 ) AS ordered_array
```

You should be able to implement that with the limited means of Hibernate.

Comment: I'll give this a swing in the morning. My goal is to avoid doing any unnecessary subquery or joins. If possible - I would much rather just create a custom aggregate that can do the ordering.